# How to write a if condition in php based on foreach loop inside a function?

Tags: php

I am a newbie here and requesting assistance in writing conditional statements based on the output of this function.

```
 $ID = '1234';
    
 $uc = array("example1.com", "example2.com", "example3.com");
    
 function ucQuery($ucarray, $ID){
    foreach ($ucarray as $value) {
        $host = $value;
        try{
            include('info.php');
            $response = $client->getUser(array("name" => ID))->return;
            print_r($response);
        }catch (Exception $e){
            echo "false";
        }
    }
    }
    
    ucQuery($uc, $ID);
```

The info.php has soapclient call to the server and returns a response. When I run this I am seeing the output printed on the page. So out of 3 servers I am expecting this to be in 1 and the rest 2 returns false. all works till here.

I am basically stuck on how to take this forward. So far example,

if the user is returned from the first example1.com server, I should run another function and say this user was returned from this particular server.

if the user is not returned from all the servers, I should print an error.

Any help here is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: shouldn't you have  `$response = $client->getUser(array("name" => $ID))->return;` instead of `$response = $client->getUser(array("name" => ID))->return;`

Comment: Yes my bad. I had to alter few code when posting here. It is $ID. Thanks.

Comment: I dont think we can help you unless you try to rewrite the question to give us more information on what this code does and what you need - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am sorry if my ask was not clear or met the expectations on how to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not something like this:

```
$ID = '1234';
    
$uc = array("example1.com", "example2.com", "example3.com");

function ucQuery($ucarray, $ID){
    $user_data_array=[];
    foreach ($ucarray as $value) {
        $host = $value;
        try{
            include('info.php');
            $response = $client->getUser(array("name" => ID))->return;
            print_r($response);
            $user_data_array[$value]=$response;
        }catch (Exception $e){
            echo "false";
        }
    }
    return $user_data_array;
}
    
$user_data_array = ucQuery($uc, $ID);

if (count($user_data_array) < count($uc)) {
    // not all servers responded OK
    // do whatever you need to
    echo "User '$ID' was not returned from all servers";
}

foreach ($user_data_array as $server => $response){
    another_function($ID, $server);
    echo "User '$ID' was returned from server $server";
}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##bVJNb4JAEL3zKyaEBEj8iLU31F7aQ@Oh6aGn1pjNMhQS3CXLrtYYf7sdWJEP5UAyO2/emzczRVpcLouXIi0c7/0VluDPnubPfuQ4nuEUMqXYMXDxj@2KHGcTLnfuCJr4aRDP6zik6sQIrjMpwPBPg@oYEF3NNQLSCU8O0OeZEtU2Zppt69zyexPViUQqZDyFWxWwErw9yw2GYGvr@lSWmpq0mej2rtWxBdVAhWUhRYkEdj/WbtTLTqeQCZ6bGAM/E4mc0DT88A7TJfF4nqHQ49Uv6i8yEVznJNgOXViugDyG45VCbZToMxUqE3qrghvdQAl5KsH9EYMmh7P6tqY3yxtPiz9zpqvpvf1xLOoteBieHqgkLC@xI3R22r/t/U43cs7VbfQfaSKdPdsV0xFkCQRcGqGDYUEIC2gyPGx2SkMWUgPLcyD4HlUJ1lyMMXysG0ws4ZAyjQSAozQgkNJaOq2vaiXgUxc@HOhyKlJrh4CJkruuRD1p8tS5uYG56vYsuNpsu7emaUb8KZU0Nx@Q8KgpuW73YV/9nq4S1zrb1uXyDw)

Comment: Thanks Dom. Your help made me working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more question. How to find if this user is returned in any two servers or maybe three? Could you help me on that please?

Comment: The $user_data_array is holding all the successful requests. So, count($user_data_array) would give you the number of successful servers. Just check for that and do what you need to.